# using preg_match to match a number between 5 and 10 characters long

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match to match a number that's between 5 and 10 characters long. However, I want the ENTIRE number. I have

```
preg_match("/\d{5, 10}/", $str, $match)
```

but the above code will match the first 5 digits of a number that is let's say 10 characters long. How can I make it return the entire length of the number?

Answer (score 1):

The quantifier syntax is `{x,y}`, not `{x,<space>y}`.

`preg_match("/\d{5,10}/", $str, $match)` works just fine.

Comment: Wow. That was really stupid of me not to see. I literally spent an hour on this. Thanks.

Comment: Protip: http://regex101.com – it *explains* what a particular regex means, which is essential for debugging.